# How to send/extract JWT token in nodejs with passport-jwt?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, passport.js, passport-jwt

I've tried to check if they're online examples of how to use `JWT extractors` to get the token from the request but I failed to understand how to send the `token` with the request after the user logins.

When I use [Postman](https://www.postman.com/), there's a tab called `Authorization` where I can choose the type `Bearer Token` which enabled me to add the `token` with the `Authorization` and the request `http://localhost:5000/profile` went successfully.

However, the browser stills showing me only `Unauthorized` when I try to access the profile `http://localhost:5000/profile` after successful login.

**POSTMAN SCREEN-SHOT:**

[image: POSTMAN-SCREENSHOT]

**BROWSER SCREEN-SHOT:**

[image: BROWSER-SCREENSHOT]

I've followed the [passpot-jwt documentation](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-jwt/) configuration:

```js
passport.use(
  new JWTStrategy(
    {
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      secretOrKey: "mysecret",
    },
    function (jwtPayload, done) {
      return User.findOne({ username: jwtPayload.username })
        .then((user) => {
          return done(null, user);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          return done(err);
        });
    }
  )
);
```

And my `login` route looks like :

```js
Router.post("/", (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("local", { session: false }, (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (!user) {
      return res.redirect("/login?info=" + info);
    }
    req.logIn(user, { session: false }, (err) => {
      if (err) return next(err);
      const token = jwt.sign({ username: user.username }, "mysecret");
      res.json({ user, token: `Bearer ${token}` });
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: Are you expecting the browser to attach the Authorization header automatically on redirect?

Comment: Now, I wanted to do it in the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The issue is:**

I was trying to access the `profile` without adding the `Authorization` in the `header` from **the server itself**. The `Authorization` contains the generated `token`.

With **Postman** I was able to do that with the **UI** as explained above. However, in the code, I needed to create a middleware before accessing the `profile` route.

```js
    app.use(
      "/profile",
      (req, res, next) => {
        req.headers.authorization = `Bearer ` + req.cookies["authentication-token"];
        next();
      },
      profileRouter
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

After login, you can send Authorization Token in headers

```
(function () {
  fetch("http://localhost:5000/profile", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "text/plain",
      "X-My-Custom-Header": "value-v",
      Authorization:
        "Bearer " + Token,
    },
  });
})();
```

Hope you got some idea.